# How to make a search engine for only specific stuff

Tags: google-chrome, search

For example one of the things i want people to be able to search from my engine is Youtube So When the person types youtube YT yt ect it takes them to youtube.com

From HTML perspective say i add a word called Youtube i will do YouTube Similarly I want to make it so when someone inserts the word youtube or similar words it takes them to youtube.com

Comment: How are you designing your search engine? Typically you'd get the user's input, then convert it to all lowercase so Youtube and YouTube mean the same thing. And then you'd have a list of keywords you'd compare the user's input to, stored inside of a database most commonly.

Comment: Im making it with HTML CSS and will add JS here is  the repo if it helps https://github.com/unofficialdxnny/scratchengine